# iOS flexible layouts

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to create a simple flexible layout:

[image: my layout]

My app has a `UITextView` (the red box) that will have a variable amount of text in it. Below it is a `UIRoundedRectButton` and a `UILabel`.

I have got the textview stretching based on the content inside already. I was wondering how I could achieve a flexible layout so the button/label are nudged down automatically if the textview has a lot of content inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put everything inside another view, and set the autoresizing on your two orange views so that they have flexible top margins, and on the red view so it has a flexible bottom margin. Resize your container view when your text changes so it is big enough to hold everything.
2. Make the whole thing a tableview with 2 or more different types of cell. The first cell holds the text field, and its height is set according to your data length. The lower cells then move down automatically. If you are using iOS 5+, this is easy to achieve using static table views and outlets. You can turn off scrolling, dividers etc. to make it look like a normal screenful of content.

Comment: Thanks for that - I've tried implementing your first suggestion but I cant seem to get it right. Here is a screenshot of where I got to - http://i.imgur.com/ujhWY.png What have I missed?

Comment: Personally I'd have gone for number 2! Not sure what's happening there, it seems to have gone all over the place. Perhaps fix the left and right margins as well, it seems to have gone over to one side.

Comment: I've played around with it some more and I just cant get option 1 to work. I think I will have to go with number 2. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

its a too simple in yourViewController delegate method `viewWillAppear` method

jus put bellow code....

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 yourTextView.text=yourdata;//here your inserted data ie.. yourdata is string variable

    yourTextView.frame = CGRectMake(yourTextView.frame.origin.x, yourTextView.frame.origin.y, yourTextView.frame.size.width, yourTextView.contentSize.height);

float btnscreen = yourTextView.frame.origin.y + yourTextView.contentSize.height + 15;

yourButton.frame=CGRectMake(yourButton.frame.origin.x, btnscreen, yourButton.frame.size.width, yourButton.frame.size.height);

float lblscreen = yourButton.frame.origin.y + yourButton.frame.size.height + 10;


yourLable.frame=CGRectMake(yourLable.frame.origin.x, lblscreen, yourLable.frame.size.width, yourLable.frame.size.height);
}
```

here,first create your view in XIB after in your .m file use this code.....
and yes if your controlls are go out of bounds then please take UIScrollView and put this controlls in your scrollview and then use this code its work fine...
hope this help you ...
:)